# EU Cookie Law: Dismiss Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using cookieconsent (https://cookieconsent.insites.com) to inform people about cookies we place.
Unfortunately people are required to accept it before cookies can be set.

But how can I disable all cookies on my website?
I could not find any easy and nice solution, also cookieconsent only gives a callback hook to work with (https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/disabling-cookies/)

Is there any solution that can be implemented?

Thanks a lot!